# use boto for gzipping files instead of sfs3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gzip, python-s3fs

```
import contextlib
import gzip

import s3fs

AWS_S3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False) # AWS env must be set up correctly

source_file_path = "/tmp/your_file.txt"
s3_file_path = "my-bucket/your_file.txt.gz"

with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    source_file = stack.enter_context(open(source_file_path , mode="rb"))
    destination_file = stack.enter_context(AWS_S3.open(s3_file_path, mode="wb"))
    destination_file_gz = stack.enter_context(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=destination_file))
    while True:
        chunk = source_file.read(1024)
        if not chunk:
            break
        destination_file_gz.write(chunk)
```

I was trying to run something like this on an AWS Lambda function but it throws an error because It Is unable to install the s3fs module. Plus, I am using boto for the remaining parts of my code so I would like to stick to boto. How I can use boto for this too?

Basically, I am opening/reading a file from a '/tmp/path', gzipping it and then saving to an S3 bucket

Edit:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('testunzipping')
s3_filename = 'samplefile.csv.'
      
   for i in testList:
        #zip_ref.open(i, ‘r’)
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            source_file = stack.enter_context(open(i , mode="rb"))
            destination_file = io.BytesIO()
            destination_file_gz = stack.enter_context(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=destination_file, mode='wb'))
            while True:
                chunk = source_file.read(1024)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                destination_file_gz.write(chunk)
            destination_file.seek(0)
            
            fileName = i.replace("/tmp/DataPump_10000838/", "") 
            bucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file, fileName)
```

Each item in the testList looks like this  `"/tmp/your_file.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AWS Lambda function but it throws an error because It Is unable to install the s3fs module

Additional packages and your own lib code (reusable code) should be put in lambda layers.

> How I can use boto for this too?

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
```

Then either:

If you have your file in memory (file-like object, open in bytes mode, e.g. `io.BytesIO` or just `open(..., 'b')`)

```
bucket.upload_fileobj(fileobj, s3_filename)
```

Or if you have a file in your current space:

```
bucket.upload_file(filepath, s3_filename)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.18.53/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_file

Comment: I know about upload_file but how do I open the file and then convert to gzip in the first place? How can I open it and gzip it? Dk how to open it in current space or in bytes mode?

Comment: Oh. You can use io.BytesIO as destination "file" in your code (then remember to go to the beginning of it before uploading fileobj, using `.seek(0)`). Or use https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.compress

Comment: 1. You changed too much from your original code, you don't have gzipping in there. 2. For your error: BytesIO() <- parens to make it an object. 3. `destination_file.seek(0)` after gzipping but before uploading (you have to "rewind" the file-like object to the beginning so the whole content can be seen)

Comment: You had while True previous when you read and wrote chunks. You don't have it now, so it's empty. ;)

Comment: As I said, seek should be after gzipping (writing, your loop) and before uploading. Right now it's before gzipping.

Comment: Ah I see I was missing the chunk writing part. Anyhow, the current code gives me ```[Errno 9] write() on read-only GzipFile object",```

Comment: Ah. Yes. You didn't give a write mode to the file. `gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=destination_file, mode='wb')` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile

Comment: ```"errorMessage": "Negative seek in write mode",```:(

Comment: Really not sure about the order of commands you're suggesting...maybe you can take a look at it when feeling fresh again XD

Comment: What I mean: `destination_file_gz.seek(0)` -> `destination_file.seek(0)` and `bucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file_gz, fileName)` -> `bucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file, fileName)` | Because _gz one is only in write mode. And it's not our original file-like object we wanted.

Comment: ```I/O operation on closed file.```:(